# Choosing a value for a choice using DomCrawler in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I'm writing a small functional test that uses DomCrawler to fill and submit a form. However, i'm having serious problems when it comes to filling choices. How can i make this work?

```
    $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/post/new');
    $form = $crawler->selectButton('new')->form();
    $form['form[name]'] = 'Test';
    $form['form[category][]'] = '1';
    $crawler = $this->client->submit($form);
```

I'm always getting an InvalidArgumentException, no matter what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a `<option />` element with a value `1`, the correct syntax for selecting it would be

```
$form['form[category]']->select('1');
```

You can read more about testing forms [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#forms).